# Water pressure regulator

Tags: plumbing

so I’ve turned my pressure regulator up and down with a gauge on my water bib and the gauge doesn’t move at all the water pressure is at 52/55psi and my water in my kitchen is at a slow slow!! ? I’m thinking maybe change the pressure regulator??

Comment: This is plenty of pressure to get a good flow from a kitchen faucet. have you unscrewed the aerator on the end of the faucet to see if this increases flow? Are any other faucets running slow?